# Error related to service manager

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running test cases in protractor and observing error message from point to point as "ERROR:service_manager.cc(425)] InterfaceProviderSpec prevented connection from: content_utility to: content_browser" which in return failing some of my test cases. I have not observed this error message before and observing it now after updates in chrome browser.

Answer (score -1):

[Find attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX8Cs.png)Run Sql server browser under services.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? If this is in fact a valid solution to an issue with Selenium Webdriver and browser automation (which has no SQL Server requirements), please give more detail.